# 'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path while creating comments Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, partials

Alright guys, as one of my projects at Bloc I am creating a reddit clone. For this particular assignment, I am to create a feature where users can comment on each post (witch is already nested within each topic). However, I am coming across this error when I try to view a post that is associated with a topic.

```
ArgumentError in Posts#show
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.
```

So far I have created comments controller, made the foreign key connection between comments and users, made the comments routes nested inside of the posts routes, created both a form partial for comment submission and a comment partial which is in post/show, and created a CommentPolicy in order to authorize users to create new comments.

I have checked my database, and comments do exist because I added them to my seed file. I suspect my error lies in my forms and my references to my partials, but I am a bit stumped. Any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

My code:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  def admin?
    role == 'admin'
  end

  def moderator?
    role == 'moderator'
  end
end
```

comment.rb

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

respective routes within routes.rb

```
  resources :topics do
    resources :posts, except: [:index] do
      resources :comments, only: [:create]
    end
  end
```

comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments = @post.comments

    @comment = current_user.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.post = @post
    @new_comment = Comment.new

    authorize @comment

      if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = "Comment was saved"
      else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error saving this comment. Please try again."
      end
  end
end
```

posts_controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    authorize @comment
  end

  def new
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new
    authorize @post
  end

  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user
    @post.topic = @topic
    authorize @post
      if @post.save
        flash[:notice] = "Post was saved."
        redirect_to [@topic, @post]
      else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error saving this post. Please try again."
        render :new
      end
  end

  def edit
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    authorize @post
  end

   def update
     @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])
     authorize @post
     if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
       flash[:notice] = "Post was updated."
       redirect_to [@topic, @post]
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
   end

   private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :image)
  end

end
```

comments/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter comment here" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Add comment", class: "btn btn-success" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

comments/_comment.html.rb

```
<%= comment.body %>
```

posts/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @post.markdown_title %></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <small>
      <%= image_tag(@post.user.avatar.tiny.url) if @post.user.avatar? %>
      submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@post.created_at) %> ago by
      <%= @post.user.name %>
    </small>
    <p><%= @post.markdown_body %></p>
    <small>
      <%= image_tag @post.image_url%> 
    </small>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <% if policy(@post).edit? %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_topic_post_path(@topic, @post), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <%= render @comments %>

    <% if policy(@comment).create? %> 
      <h4>New Comment</h4>
      <%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>
    <% end %>
```

comment_policy

```
class CommentPolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  def new
    user.present?
  end

  def create
    user.present?
  end

end
```

comments within seed file

```
#Create Comments
100.times do
    Comment.create!(
        user: users.sample,   # we have not yet associated Users with Comments
        post: posts.sample,
        body: Faker:: Lorem.paragraph
    )
end
comments = Comment.all
```

Answer (score 0):

The believe the error is in this line

```
<%= render @comments %>
```

in your `posts/show.html.erb`

You don't have `@comments` defined in `show` method of `posts_controller`. Try putting `@comments = @post.comments` in `show` method.

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  authorize @comment
  @comments = @post.comments
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to see comments when a user is not signed in, but when I do sign in, I see the following error: ```comments/_form.html.erb:1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting :: or '[' or '.' ...m for [topic, post, comment] do |f| @output_buffer.safe_appe... ... ^ /Users/sethjones/code/bloccit/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb:10: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input```

Comment: and it highlights ```<%= form for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>``` in the comments/_form and  ```<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>``` in posts/show

Comment: @user3700231 This is wrong `@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])`. Try debugging it

Comment: Ahhh I noticed a syntax issue in my form. I changed ```<%= form for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>``` to ```<%= form_for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>``` And now I'm getting this error ```undefined method `topic_post_comment_path``` and it highlights ```<%= form_for [topic, post, comment] do |f| %>``` in comments/form and ```<%= render partial: 'comments/form', locals: { topic: @topic, post: @post, comment: @comment } %>``` in posts/show